# Find which two values of an array a given value is belongs

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose I have an array similar to this:

```
$months = Array('3','6','12','15','18','21','24');
```

and I have `$n = 5`, what would be a good way to find that `$n` falls in array ?
also element should be append after 3 & before 6 because 5 in between 3 & 6

```
e.g.
$n = 5; then array will be
$months = Array('3','5','6','12','15','18','21','24');

$n = 7; then array will be
$months = Array('3','6','7','12','15','18','21','24');
```

also i need to display progress according to $n

```
 e.g.
 $n=3 then up to $3 color will get filled

 $n=5 then color will get filled up to middle of 3 & 5
```

i have placed array value on div & i need to display progress accordingly.

PROGRESS BAR EXAMPLE
http://awesomescreenshot.com/04937zko93

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve regarding show of progress. Can you give a visual example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `months` array is initially sorted, we iterate through that array and find the exact position to insert `$n`, partition that array in two and insert `$n` in middle of the slices

```
for($pos = 0; $pos < count($months); $pos++) {
    if($months[$pos] > $n) {
        break;
    }
}
$end_part     = array_slice($months, $pos);
$first_part   = array_slice($months, 0, $pos);
$first_part[] = $n;
$months       = array_merge($first_part, $end_part);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to insert the value at the correct position in your array:

```
$months = [3, 6, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24];
$n = 5;

$idx = count(array_filter($months, function($val) use($n) {
    return $val < $n;
}));

array_splice($months, $idx, 0, [$n]);
```

This is how to calculate the progress to use for your progress bar, assuming that:

1. The first value (3 in this example) is 0%
2. That the last value (24) is 100%, and
3. There is the same difference between each number in the array (3 in this case)

-

```
$pct = ($n - min($months)) / (max($months) - min($months)) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = 7;
$months = Array('3','6','12','15','18','21','24');

$i = 0;
foreach ($months as $k => $v) {
    if ($n < $v) {
        $months = array_merge(array_slice($months, 0, $i), array("$n"), array_slice($months, $i, count($months)));
        break;
    }
    ++$i;
}
var_dump($months);
```